# Meaning of "that's off" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I encounter it in the 22nd episode of the 9th season of *Friends*. Here is the context:

> Phoebe: (entering and talking on mobile phone) Ok, great! All right,
> bye! (she hangs up) Pain in the ass!! (she looks at the others, then
> back at the phone) **That's off**, right?
>
> Joey: What's the matter, Pheebs?
>
> Phoebe: Oh... Mike's sister just invited me to a party tonight, he's
> gonna be there. And she was like "Oh, don't worry! I asked him. He's
> totally ok with seeing you!". So now I have to go so he'll think that
> I'm totally ok with seeing him!

Comment: **looks back at the phone**= That's off, right? Meaning: The phone is off, right? That and this in speech. You might want tor review that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She is speaking her thoughts.  She has just said something rude about the person that she was talking to on the phone. So she thinks  "Is the phone off" but being Phoebe (and because it is funny) she speaks her thoughts out loud.

By "off" she probably doesn't mean that the phone is completely turned off, but just that the line has been hung up.  (It was a 90s phone, so if you weren't calling somebody it was basically "off")

Comment: "That's off" refers to the phone that she is pointing at. She is having a conversation, actually.It's a cell phone. It is not a landline....Your answer makes little sense to me. It's clearly a dialogue from the show.

Comment: Thats what I said.

Comment: No, you said: She is speaking her thoughts. **It is a dialogue and she is speaking to the other people who are there**. Also, it implies she is pointing or otherwise signaling the phone by using "that's".

Comment: I don't think she is speaking to other people at all.  She was speaking on the phone, and then after hanging up she is rude to the other person, then worries if the other person might still be listening.  When she says "That's off, right", its not a question that she expects the others to answer.  Note that Joey does reply "Yes, it's off".  He says "What's the matter". This is the (comic) character of Phoebe: she says what she's thinking, and often her thoughts are strange or funny.

Comment: It is dialogue: (**she looks at the others, then back at the phone**) That's off, right?