# What is the meaning of the "That's In-off"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

In the series **["Secret Army 1977~79", season 2, episode 5, at 13:00](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0697320/?ref_=m_ttep_ep_ep5)**,
Albert gives Monique a bottle of perfume.  After smelling the perfume, Monique moves it to Albert's face and then quickly pulls her hand back.  [Monique] at this time [with a smile] He says such a term:

> «Smell it, **That's in-off**»

[image: Secret Army series,s2e5, 14:11]

Before asking this question, I searched the website about it and  found a similar question:

> **[Meaning of "that's off" in context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/253157/meaning-of-thats-off-in-context/318487#318487)**

I read the answers but unfortunately it didn't give me an acceptable result.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to say what it is she says. It is too fuzzy.

Comment: This is a question based on a misinterpretation by the OP (the subtitles in the picture were written by them): do we close this?

Comment: I’m closing this question because it's based on a mishearing. The character doesn't say "in-off".

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me as though the sub-title mistook the word “enough” for “inoff.”

Comment: I've downloaded the actual episode (don't ask how), and also a srt subtitle file from a subtitle site. She doesn't say anything like 'That's in-off', or 'that's enough'. She make a very brief unintelligible exclamation, a bit like 'achel! (a-choo)? and giggles.' The srt file shows nothing except `Oh, it's lovely. Smell it.` I do not know where the OP got those subtitles from.

Comment: There is a child’s game where one whispers to another and then to another in a long chain to see how scrambled the meaning can get. I wonder if that is what happened here.

Comment: Thanks"Jeff Morrow.  I think your answer is completely correct because by replacing the word "enough" with "in-off" the meaning of the sentence is correct.

Comment: @michael-harvey Thanks for the answer. I watch movies and series without subtitles [to learn English]. I wrote the text inside the image with the app to take a screenshot. There was no such text in the subtitle that I downloaded from the Opensubtitle site. That's why I asked this question here.

Comment: @aksvare - but she doesn't say that. I've listened to it.

Comment: So I misunderstood. Thank you

Comment: According to your answers, there is no such term in English? (That's In-off)

Comment: @aksvare - there is no such 'term' (which is really a name for something).

Comment: I watched and listened using good headphones at [Dailymotion](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x7n4c89) (it's at 13:02). She says 'Achoo!' and giggles. We says 'Achoo!' when we pretend to sneeze.

Comment: @JeffMorrow - better not say what that game used to be called.

Comment: I don't understand why there's any debate about this. To my ears she absolutely, 100%, no doubt about it, says, "That's enough!". At that time, a gift of perfume was a rare and valuable thing, and she is showing her understanding of that, and her appreciation of the gift in general, by restricting (playfully) the amount of it that she is willing to sacrifice even to him smelling it. It's as clear as day.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, we used to call that game *Shy Knees Whispers*, but apparently that is now regarded as being offensive to knees.